# Why do people keep getting knocked off of steep slopes in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

In most of the Star Wars movies, someone gets thrown off a platform on a Empire or First Order ship.  Why do they have platforms/bridges like that?

Comment: Can you give some examples? I can only think of three at the top of my head, and technically none of them occurred on an Empire or First Order ship.

Comment: I HAVE THE HIGH GROUND~!

Comment: Duplicate, I think. There was an earlier question about high places and lack of safety barriers

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Star Wars universe as a whole has a very poor safety rating.

[Are guard rails important](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24885/safety-railings-in-the-star-wars-universe)? Apparently not. I guess falling 6 feet into a pit isn't a concern, even with a narrow walkway.

[image]

Even here, in this incredibly dangerous place, there is no safety rail for what is clearly a series of consoles and controls.

[image]

All the landing platforms are really high up, but I guess no one ever tripped and fell to their death, resulting in a lawsuit.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Star Wars: Where safety doesn't come first.**

Comment: Clearly they need OSHA to come in and perform a safety inspection.

Comment: On railings - see https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24885/safety-railings-in-the-star-wars-universe