# How did people in the Star Wars galaxy handle travelling to planets with different gravity?

Tags: star-wars

We see people travel to different planets of various sizes, but nothing to show the gravitational differences?  In legends, there are comments about how the increased gravity on the trooper academy on Carida has led to stronger troops, but not elsewhere.

In canon, do they show or talk about how people handle going to places where gravity is different than their 'normal' environment?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but of course I could be totally wrong!

Comment: Almost all of the planets seen in the movies (Coruscant, Naboo, Tatoine, Jakku etc) seem very Earth-like, so I guess gravity is the same. Not sure about Legends though.

Comment: Star Wars physics doesn't really seem to *do* gravity.  For example, see [Concord Dawn](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Concord_Dawn).  Or perhaps gravity is Aristotelian rather than Newtonian, or something like that.

Comment: I'd imagine they do what most travelers do when they're force to go to a strange place, they feel crappy for a bit and then get used to it eventually

Comment: I've tended to assume that there are so many zillions of habitable, Earthlike planets in the Star Wars galaxy that human colonists can afford to be **very** choosy. If a planet's surface gravity is, let's say, less than 0.80g or more than 1.20g, maybe the human explorers just say, "Heck with it, we'll leave this one alone, and some species whose native environment is a lot closer to local conditions can colonize this newly-discovered world instead! Let's move on to the *next* possibility on our list!" But I have no "canonical support" for that personal hypothesis.

Comment: @Lorendiac That makes sense, but at the same time, if those people are in the Republic, then they'd have to find a way to handle being on Coruscant's gravity.

Comment: "*As his next target, Kyp would challenge the Imperial military training center on Carida. The military planet was a largish world with high gravity to toughen the muscles of potential stormtroopers. Its untamed land masses provided an appropriate range of training environments: arctic wastelands, trackless rain forests, splintered mountain crags, and searing desert hardpan crawling with venomous multilegged reptiles.* - Jedi  Academy #1, Champions of the Force

Comment: This is related to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24885/safety-railings-in-the-star-wars-universe

Comment: Also related to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112709/why-do-people-keep-getting-knocked-off-of-steep-slopes-in-star-wars/112711#112711

Comment: @blueberryfields I don't think they are related at all. This one is about adapting to the gravity of different planets, those are about safety measures (or lack thereof).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Canon

In *[The Legends of Luke Skywalker](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Legends_of_Luke_Skywalker)*, Luke and a scientist visit an asteroid with low gravity. They move around with some difficulty.

> Gravity on the asteroid was light but sufficient to keep us securely rooted to the surface. Gingerly, we hop-walked to the cave, whose mouth was smoothly polished, as though it had been carved out by a river. I was baffled by the unusual geologic feature. An asteroid that small couldn’t have had flowing water.

In [the novel *Ahsoka*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ahsoka_(novel)), we learn that people who live and work in low gravity environments often struggle with their breathing, which probably explains why we don't really see many low-gee worlds.

> All that fuss for a plant. Just a simple plant that could be processed into a nutritional supplement that allowed people working in low gravity to process oxygen more efficiently. He couldn’t imagine it was worth the trouble the Empire had gone to in order to procure it.

Answer (score 4):

The tech in the *Star Wars* universe is heavily based on gravity manipulation (the visual dictionary is a good source for this).  Repulsorlifts are a good example.  The dorsal and ventral guns on the Millennium Falcon as well.

It's quite possible everyone wears a gravity manipulation belt when on a planet with significantly higher gravity.

Comment: Other people have also wondered the same thing: [Why is gravity the same on every planet?](https://www.reddit.com/r/StarWars/comments/4v9shx/why_is_gravity_the_same_on_every_planet/)

Comment: Any sources on the existence of such belts?

Comment: @Mixxiphoid - not yet, but there does seem to be evidence of gravity manipulation on a moon/planet level.  Starkiller Base, for instance, doesn't make sense without gravity manipulation on a planetary scale.  Perhaps all inhabited moons and planets are terraformed including gravity manipulation.

Comment: Gravity manipulation belts are an important enough scifi concept that they would have been mentioned *somewhere*, especially if use was widespread. So I think they are not in use in Star Wars.